# Get value from string python

Tags: python, string

Can someone help me? I want to transform this string

`"[(14577003, 0.05889), (14066001, 0.04027)]"`

to

`[(14577003, 0.05889), (14066001, 0.04027)]`
by removing the quotes. How can I do that in Python ?

Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: You mean that you want to transform the string into a list of tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can eval the content of the string, so you get the content as a list:

```
ll = eval("[(14577003, 0.05889), (14066001, 0.04027)]")
ll
```

output is:

```
[(14577003, 0.05889), (14066001, 0.04027)]
```

You also have a safer way to do it:

```
import ast
ll = ast.literal_eval("[(14577003, 0.05889), (14066001, 0.04027)]")
ll
```

The ast.literal_eval() is a a safe eval() that only evaluates literals such as strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, None and Ellipsis. This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.
See http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: This answer will work. Note, however, that using `eval` is considered a dangerous practice, as it poses a significant security risk (you let your user execute arbitrary code). The real question here is, in fact, why are you receiving data as formatted Python literals. There are multiple ways of transferring data that can be efficiently encoded and decoded without having to resort to `eval`.

Comment: you can use a safer method: ast.literal_eval  see edited answer

Comment: you can also consider using some librairies like json , pickle ... or others depending on the way you transmit/receive data.